# Does Hibernate put collection that was retrived from data base to first lvl cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Can someone explain me is it true that hibernate put collection to first lvl cache

is it looks like

frist request by RestController

```
@GetMapping("/findfoo")
public List<Foo> findFoo(){
List<Foo> listFirst=fooRepository.findAll();
return listFirst;
}
```

hibernate will do this : select * from foo;
and second requet

```
List<foo> listTwo=fooRepositoy.findAll();
```

hibernate will get listFirst from first lvl cache ?or it will do the same select to data base?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65756768/entity-not-returned-from-l1-cache/) will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entities are put in the 1st level cache (the session) but not the result of queries, for that you would need to enable the 2nd level query cache.

To put it differently, the Hibernate session keeps track of all the entities whether they are loaded from a query (as it is the case here) or by lazy loading an association from another entity.

If you do the query twice, it will the database with the 2nd query too, however Hibernate will return the same java objects (== identity, not equals() identity).

Comment: do i right understood you -that the Hibernate does not put the real elements of collection to first level cache by default?

Comment: To put it differently if i do  entityManager.find() i will retrive the same list as i got here List<Foo> listFirst=fooRepository.findAll();?? that means it will be in memory all the time while session is on?

Comment: The real elements of the collection are in the 1st level cache by default, but the list of these elements is not.

Comment: and wat will happen if there are to many elements and memory is full?

Comment: If the memory is full the JVM will throw an OutOfMemoryException at some point when Hibernate tries to create these objects.